Sudo nixos-rebuild switch do not update boot entry and previous configuratin is booted
after running the command sudo nixos-rebuild switch
and comparing /run/current-system/ and /run/booted-system/ shows the following differences: all the software and services are working properly.
 diff <(ls -l /run/current-system/ | sort) <(ls -l /run/booted-system/ | sort)
3,4c3,4
< lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   51 Jan  1  1970 etc -> /nix/store/83d39jhvp1xqzhkvc6zwfgyggvxqmfmn-etc/etc
< lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   55 Jan  1  1970 sw -> /nix/store/6cvd70z2awlac6w931kyynm6lhd458sy-system-path
---
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   51 Jan  1  1970 etc -> /nix/store/4wwgmkdpqmr2387kn6rqsa8k5brh03x1-etc/etc
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   55 Jan  1  1970 sw -> /nix/store/vlqf9rhfcq6ss74syj67xln9a4g1az26-system-path
9c9
< lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   70 Jan  1  1970 initrd -> /nix/store/2z1dx44vv15a1i3i8j4xb7nh4v6d438d-initrd-linux-6.8.12/initrd
---
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   70 Jan  1  1970 initrd -> /nix/store/24g94lvvmw08lqqjjig9kkdh6fq8123n-initrd-linux-6.8.12/initrd
11d10
< -r--r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jan  1  1970 configuration-name
16c15
< -r--r--r-- 1 root root  602 Jan  1  1970 boot.json
---
> -r--r--r-- 1 root root  660 Jan  1  1970 boot.json

But after reboot it boots in to same old configuration.
list generation with nixos-rebuild list-generations shows, and it is not updated after nixos-rebuild
Generation  Build-date           NixOS version            Kernel  Configuration Revision  Specialisation
22 current  2024-07-03 13:38:01  24.05.2355.d032c1a6dfad  6.8.12                          *
21          2024-07-03 01:00:00  24.05.2355.d032c1a6dfad  6.8.12                          *

My configuration files
I am using docker, proxmox and cloudflare in a multifile config as follows
configuration.nix
{ config, pkgs, lib, ... }:

{
    users.users.prateek.extraGroups = [ "docker" ];

    virtualisation.docker = {
      enable = true;
      rootless.enable = true;
    };



    environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
        docker
#        nvidia-docker
        docker-compose
    ];


    services.dockerRegistry.enable = true;

}

[prateek@nixos:/etc/nixos]$ cat configuration.nix
{ pkgs, lib, config, ... }:

{
  imports = [
                ./hardware-configuration.nix
                ./proxmox.nix
                ./cloudflare.nix
                ./docker.nix
            ];




  # Edit this configuration file to define what should be installed on
# your system.  Help is available in the configuration.nix(5) man page
# and in the NixOS manual (accessible by running ‘nixos-help’).

  options= {};

  config = {

  # System-wide settings
  system.autoUpgrade.enable = true;     # Enable automatic system upgrades
  system.autoUpgrade.allowReboot = true;
  system.autoUpgrade.channel = "https://channels.nixos.org/nixos-24.05";



  nix.settings.experimental-features = [ "nix-command" "flakes" ];







# # Bootloader settings
  boot.loader = {
#     systemd-boot.enable = true;
    grub = {
      enable = true;
      zfsSupport = true;
      devices = ["nodev"];
      efiSupport = true;
      useOSProber = true;
    };
  };

  # Filesystem support
  boot.supportedFilesystems = [ "ntfs" ];

  # ZFS settings
  boot.kernelPackages = config.boot.zfs.package.latestCompatibleLinuxPackages;
  boot.zfs.extraPools = [ "zpool_name" ];
  services.zfs.autoScrub.enable = true;










  # Networking settings

  networking.hostName = "nixos"; # Define your hostname.
  networking.wireless.enable = true;  # Enables wireless support via wpa_supplicant.

  # Configure network proxy if necessary
  # networking.proxy.default = "http://user:password@proxy:port/";
  # networking.proxy.noProxy = "127.0.0.1,localhost,internal.domain";

  # Enable networking
  networking.networkmanager.enable = true;

  # Set your time zone.
  time.timeZone = "Asia/Kolkata";

  # Select internationalisation properties.
  i18n.defaultLocale = "en_IN";

  i18n.extraLocaleSettings = {
    LC_ADDRESS = "en_IN";
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_IN";
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_IN";
    LC_MONETARY = "en_IN";
    LC_NAME = "en_IN";
    LC_NUMERIC = "en_IN";
    LC_PAPER = "en_IN";
    LC_TELEPHONE = "en_IN";
    LC_TIME = "en_IN";
  };

  # Enable the X11 windowing system.
  services.xserver.enable = true;

  # Enable the Cinnamon Desktop Environment.
  services.xserver.displayManager.lightdm.enable = true;
  services.xserver.desktopManager.cinnamon.enable = true;

  services.libinput.enable = true;  # Enable libinput for touchpad


  # Configure keymap in X11
  services.xserver = {
#    layout = "us";
    xkb =   {
                variant = "";
                layout = "us";
            };
  };



















  # Enable sound with pipewire.
  hardware.pulseaudio.enable = false;
  security.rtkit.enable = true;
  services.pipewire = {
    enable = true;
    alsa.enable = true;
    alsa.support32Bit = true;
    pulse.enable = true;
    # If you want to use JACK applications, uncomment this
    #jack.enable = true;

    # use the example session manager (no others are packaged yet so this is enabled by default,
    # no need to redefine it in your config for now)
    #media-session.enable = true;
  };

  # Enable touchpad support (enabled default in most desktopManager).
  # services.xserver.libinput.enable = true;











  # Define a user account. Don't forget to set a password with ‘passwd’.
  users.users.prateek = {
    isNormalUser = true;
    description = "prateek";
    extraGroups = [ "networkmanager" "wheel" "docker" "vagrant" "virtualbox" "wireshark" ];
    packages = with pkgs; [
      thunderbird
    ];
  };





  # Enable automatic login for the user.
  services.displayManager.autoLogin = {
                                        enable = true;
                                        user = "prateek";
                                       };











 # Security settings
  security.sudo.extraRules = [
    {
      users = [ "privileged_user" ];
      commands = [
        {
          command = "ALL";
          options = [ "NOPASSWD" ];
          # options = [ "NOPASSWD", "SETENV" ];  # Example of additional options
        }
      ];
    }
  ];










  # Install firefox.
  programs.firefox.enable = true;

  # Allow unfree packages
  nixpkgs.config.allowUnfree = true;









  # Virtualization settings
  virtualisation = {
#    docker = {
#      enable = true;
#      rootless.enable = true;
#    };
    virtualbox = {
      host = {
        enable = true;
        enableExtensionPack = true;
      };
    };
  };





  # List packages installed in system profile. To search, run:
  # $ nix search wget
  environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
    wget
    vim
    netboot
    tftp-hpa
    syslinux
    zip
    gnutar
    bash
    blender
    inkscape
    helm
    lmms
    audacity
    gimp
    redshift
    vscodium-fhs
    vscode
    mendeley
    podman
    gparted
    brave
    arduino
    freecad
    git
    chromium
    google-chrome
    pdfsam-basic
    libreoffice
    pandoc
    texlive.combined.scheme-full
    texworks
    neovim
    marktext
    telegram-desktop
    teamviewer
    copyq
    fsearch
    nodejs
    nodePackages.nodemon
    nodePackages_latest.npm
    python3Full
    pipenv
    platformio
    tor-browser-bundle-bin
    gscan2pdf
    obs-studio
    wine
    wine64
    winetricks
    gccgo13
    gns3-server
    gns3-gui
    wireshark
    shotcut
    ffmpeg_5
    vlc
    rustup
    vagrant
    scilab-bin
    droidcam
#    dhcp
    samba
    avahi
    kicad
    xournalpp
    gedit
    ntfs3g
    veracrypt
    x11vnc
    turbovnc
    dpkg
    wget
    unetbootin
    zfs
    tailscale
    npins
    android-studio
    android-tools
    screen
  ] ++  [ python3Packages.pip python3Packages.django python3Packages.fastapi python3Packages.uvicorn  ];


 # Package override example
  nixpkgs.config.packageOverrides = pkgs: {
    xsaneGimp = pkgs.xsane.override { gimpSupport = true; };
  };















  # Some programs need SUID wrappers, can be configured further or are
  # started in user sessions.
  # programs.mtr.enable = true;
  # programs.gnupg.agent = {
  #   enable = true;
  #   enableSSHSupport = true;
  # };

  # List services that you want to enable:
# Services configuration
  services.devmon.enable = true;
  services.gvfs.enable = true;
  services.udisks2.enable = true;
  services.avahi.enable = true;
  services.avahi.nssmdns4 = true;
  services.teamviewer.enable = true;
#  services.dockerRegistry.enable = true;
  services.tailscale.enable = true;

  # Enable the OpenSSH daemon.
   services.openssh.enable = true;

  # Open ports in the firewall.
  # networking.firewall.allowedTCPPorts = [ ... ];
  # networking.firewall.allowedUDPPorts = [ ... ];
  # Or disable the firewall altogether.
  # networking.firewall.enable = false;

  networking.firewall = {
    allowedTCPPorts = [ 22 80 5900 ];
    allowedUDPPorts = [ 22 80 5900 ];
  };








  # Printing services
  services.printing = {
    enable = true; # Enable CUPS to print documents.
    drivers = [ pkgs.brgenml1cupswrapper ];
  };




  # This value determines the NixOS release from which the default
  # settings for stateful data, like file locations and database versions
  # on your system were taken. It‘s perfectly fine and recommended to leave
  # this value at the release version of the first install of this system.
  # Before changing this value read the documentation for this option
  # (e.g. man configuration.nix or on https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html).
  system.stateVersion = "24.05"; # Did you read the comment?


 };#end config

}

docker.nix
{ config, pkgs, lib, ... }:

{
    users.users.prateek.extraGroups = [ "docker" ];

    virtualisation.docker = {
      enable = true;
      rootless.enable = true;
    };



    environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
        docker
#        nvidia-docker
        docker-compose
    ];


    services.dockerRegistry.enable = true;

}

cloudflare.nix
{ config, lib, pkgs, ... }:

{
environment.systemPackages = [ pkgs.cloudflared ];




 users.users.cloudflared = {
    group = "cloudflared";
    isSystemUser = true;
  };
  users.groups.cloudflared = { };


    systemd.services.my_tunnel = {
    wantedBy = [ "multi-user.target" ];
#    after = [ "network.target" ];
    after = [ "network-online.target" "systemd-resolved.service" ];
    serviceConfig = {
      ExecStart = "${pkgs.cloudflared}/bin/cloudflared tunnel --no-autoupdate run --token=mytokenreplacedhere";
#      ExecStart = "${pkgs.cloudflared}/bin/cloudflared tunnel --no-autoupdate run --credentials-file=/home/prateek/cloudflare.token";
      Restart = "always";
      User = "cloudflared";
      Group = "cloudflared";
    };
  };


}

proxmox.nix
{ config, pkgs, lib, ... }:
let
  sources = import ./npins;
  proxmox-nixos = import sources.proxmox-nixos;

in
{
  imports = [
        proxmox-nixos.nixosModules.proxmox-ve
        ];

  services.proxmox-ve.enable = true;
  nixpkgs.overlays = [
    proxmox-nixos.overlays.x86_64-linux
  ];

  environment.systemPackages = [ pkgs.npins ];





# Network for VM

## Script mode
#  networking.bridges.vmbr0.interfaces = [ "ens18" ];

  networking.bridges.vmbr0.interfaces = [ "enp3s0" ];
  networking.interfaces.vmbr0.useDHCP = lib.mkDefault true;


# https://github.com/SaumonNet/proxmox-nixos
}


I am also using git to keep track of my configuration and all the files are staged, committed, and pushed


for proxmox I have initialize npins in /etc/nixos/ using npins init and npins add github SaumonNet proxmox-nixos -b main

boot config
\boot\grub\grub.cfg
# Automatically generated.  DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE!

    search --set=drive1 --fs-uuid FDDE-ED3B
    if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
      load_env
    fi

    # ‘grub-reboot’ sets a one-time saved entry, which we process here and
    # then delete.
    if [ "${next_entry}" ]; then
      set default="${next_entry}"
      set next_entry=
      save_env next_entry
      set timeout=1
      set boot_once=true
    else
      set default=0
      set timeout=5
    fi
    set timeout_style=menu

    function savedefault {
        if [ -z "${boot_once}"]; then
        saved_entry="${chosen}"
        save_env saved_entry
        fi
    }

    # Setup the graphics stack for bios and efi systems
    if [ "${grub_platform}" = "efi" ]; then
      insmod efi_gop
      insmod efi_uga
    else
      insmod vbe
    fi

        insmod font
        if loadfont ($drive1)//converted-font.pf2; then
          insmod gfxterm
          if [ "${grub_platform}" = "efi" ]; then
            set gfxmode=auto
            set gfxpayload=keep
          else
            set gfxmode=1024x768
            set gfxpayload=text
          fi
          terminal_output gfxterm
        fi

        background_color '#2F302F'

        insmod png
        if background_image --mode 'normal' ($drive1)//background.png; then
          set color_normal=white/black
          set color_highlight=black/white
        else
          set menu_color_normal=cyan/blue
          set menu_color_highlight=white/blue
        fi


menuentry "NixOS" --class nixos --unrestricted {
search --set=drive1 --fs-uuid FDDE-ED3B
  linux ($drive1)//kernels/qqsr6iqnbsqimsr09ryjf4a06a4zcx95-linux-6.8.12-bzImage init=/nix/store/2xfw4p1vr2k5i44ka9b2aprars8y2dfl-nixos-system-nixos-24.05.2355.d032c1a6dfad/init loglevel=4
  initrd ($drive1)//kernels/2z1dx44vv15a1i3i8j4xb7nh4v6d438d-initrd-linux-6.8.12-initrd
}


submenu "NixOS - All configurations" --class submenu {
menuentry "NixOS - Configuration 24 (2024-07-03 - 24.05.2355.d032c1a6dfad)" --class nixos {
search --set=drive1 --fs-uuid FDDE-ED3B
  linux ($drive1)//kernels/qqsr6iqnbsqimsr09ryjf4a06a4zcx95-linux-6.8.12-bzImage init=/nix/store/2xfw4p1vr2k5i44ka9b2aprars8y2dfl-nixos-system-nixos-24.05.2355.d032c1a6dfad/init loglevel=4
  initrd ($drive1)//kernels/2z1dx44vv15a1i3i8j4xb7nh4v6d438d-initrd-linux-6.8.12-initrd
}

menuentry "NixOS - Configuration 23 (2024-07-03 - 24.05.2355.d032c1a6dfad)" --class nixos {
search --set=drive1 --fs-uuid FDDE-ED3B
  linux ($drive1)//kernels/qqsr6iqnbsqimsr09ryjf4a06a4zcx95-linux-6.8.12-bzImage init=/nix/store/fysmc31k8ilxhvd9nk1i1cdvgwdfhyns-nixos-system-nixos-24.05.2355.d032c1a6dfad/init loglevel=4
  initrd ($drive1)//kernels/24g94lvvmw08lqqjjig9kkdh6fq8123n-initrd-linux-6.8.12-initrd
}

menuentry "NixOS - Configuration 22 (2024-07-03 - 24.05.2355.d032c1a6dfad)" --class nixos {
search --set=drive1 --fs-uuid FDDE-ED3B
  linux ($drive1)//kernels/qqsr6iqnbsqimsr09ryjf4a06a4zcx95-linux-6.8.12-bzImage init=/nix/store/2xfw4p1vr2k5i44ka9b2aprars8y2dfl-nixos-system-nixos-24.05.2355.d032c1a6dfad/init loglevel=4
  initrd ($drive1)//kernels/2z1dx44vv15a1i3i8j4xb7nh4v6d438d-initrd-linux-6.8.12-initrd
}

menuentry "NixOS - Configuration 21 (2024-07-03 - 24.05.2355.d032c1a6dfad)" --class nixos {
search --set=drive1 --fs-uuid FDDE-ED3B
  linux ($drive1)//kernels/qqsr6iqnbsqimsr09ryjf4a06a4zcx95-linux-6.8.12-bzImage init=/nix/store/1gyc6rcdjhw85an8caxl7zqlnpmxgbpl-nixos-system-nixos-24.05.2355.d032c1a6dfad/init loglevel=4
  initrd ($drive1)//kernels/2z1dx44vv15a1i3i8j4xb7nh4v6d438d-initrd-linux-6.8.12-initrd
}

}
menuentry 'Linux Mint 21.2 Victoria (21.2) (on /dev/sda4)' --class linuxmint --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-simple-fe714422-edd3-480d-8f2e-17ff70f3b0a1' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt4'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt4  fe714422-edd3-480d-8f2e-17ff70f3b0a1
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fe714422-edd3-480d-8f2e-17ff70f3b0a1
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-89-generic root=UUID=fe714422-edd3-480d-8f2e-17ff70f3b0a1 ro quiet splash
        initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-89-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Linux Mint 21.2 Victoria (21.2) (on /dev/sda4)' $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-advanced-fe714422-edd3-480d-8f2e-17ff70f3b0a1' {
        menuentry 'Linux Mint 21.2 Cinnamon (on /dev/sda4)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-89-generic--fe714422-edd3-480d-8f2e-17ff70f3b0a1' {
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd0,gpt4'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt4  fe714422-edd3-480d-8f2e-17ff70f3b0a1
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fe714422-edd3-480d-8f2e-17ff70f3b0a1
                fi
                linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-89-generic root=UUID=fe714422-edd3-480d-8f2e-17ff70f3b0a1 ro quiet splash
                initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-89-generic
        }
        menuentry 'Linux Mint 21.2 Cinnamon, with Linux 5.15.0-89-generic (on /dev/sda4)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-89-generic--fe714422-edd3-480d-8f2e-17ff70f3b0a1' {
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd0,gpt4'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt4  fe714422-edd3-480d-8f2e-17ff70f3b0a1
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fe714422-edd3-480d-8f2e-17ff70f3b0a1
                fi
                linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-89-generic root=UUID=fe714422-edd3-480d-8f2e-17ff70f3b0a1 ro quiet splash
                initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-89-generic
        }
        menuentry 'Linux Mint 21.2 Cinnamon, with Linux 5.15.0-89-generic (recovery mode) (on /dev/sda4)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-89-generic--fe714422-edd3-480d-8f2e-17ff70f3b0a1' {
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd0,gpt4'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt4  fe714422-edd3-480d-8f2e-17ff70f3b0a1
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fe714422-edd3-480d-8f2e-17ff70f3b0a1
                fi
                linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-89-generic root=UUID=fe714422-edd3-480d-8f2e-17ff70f3b0a1 ro recovery nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr
                initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-89-generic
        }
        menuentry 'Linux Mint 21.2 Cinnamon, with Linux 5.15.0-76-generic (on /dev/sda4)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-76-generic--fe714422-edd3-480d-8f2e-17ff70f3b0a1' {
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd0,gpt4'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt4  fe714422-edd3-480d-8f2e-17ff70f3b0a1
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fe714422-edd3-480d-8f2e-17ff70f3b0a1
                fi
                linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-76-generic root=UUID=fe714422-edd3-480d-8f2e-17ff70f3b0a1 ro quiet splash
                initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-76-generic
        }
        menuentry 'Linux Mint 21.2 Cinnamon, with Linux 5.15.0-76-generic (recovery mode) (on /dev/sda4)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-76-generic--fe714422-edd3-480d-8f2e-17ff70f3b0a1' {
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd0,gpt4'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt4  fe714422-edd3-480d-8f2e-17ff70f3b0a1
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fe714422-edd3-480d-8f2e-17ff70f3b0a1
                fi
                linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-76-generic root=UUID=fe714422-edd3-480d-8f2e-17ff70f3b0a1 ro recovery nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr
                initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-76-generic
        }
}

menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) (on /dev/sdb3)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-simple-8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd1,gpt3'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt3 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt3 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt3  8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.13-3-pve root=UUID=8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956 ro quiet
        initrd /boot/initrd.img-6.5.13-3-pve
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) (on /dev/sdb3)' $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-advanced-8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956' {
        menuentry 'Proxmox VE GNU/Linux (on /dev/sdb3)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.13-3-pve--8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956' {
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd1,gpt3'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt3 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt3 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt3  8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956
                fi
                linux /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.13-3-pve root=UUID=8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956 ro quiet
                initrd /boot/initrd.img-6.5.13-3-pve
        }
        menuentry 'Proxmox VE GNU/Linux, with Linux 6.5.13-3-pve (on /dev/sdb3)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.13-3-pve--8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956' {
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd1,gpt3'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt3 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt3 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt3  8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956
                fi
                linux /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.13-3-pve root=UUID=8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956 ro quiet
                initrd /boot/initrd.img-6.5.13-3-pve
        }
        menuentry 'Proxmox VE GNU/Linux, with Linux 6.5.13-3-pve (recovery mode) (on /dev/sdb3)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.13-3-pve-root=UUID=8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956 ro single-8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956' {
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd1,gpt3'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt3 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt3 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt3  8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956
                fi
                linux /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.13-3-pve root=UUID=8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956 ro single
                initrd /boot/initrd.img-6.5.13-3-pve
        }
        menuentry 'Proxmox VE GNU/Linux, with Linux 6.5.11-4-pve (on /dev/sdb3)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.11-4-pve--8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956' {
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd1,gpt3'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt3 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt3 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt3  8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956
                fi
                linux /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.11-4-pve root=UUID=8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956 ro quiet
                initrd /boot/initrd.img-6.5.11-4-pve
        }
        menuentry 'Proxmox VE GNU/Linux, with Linux 6.5.11-4-pve (recovery mode) (on /dev/sdb3)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.11-4-pve-root=UUID=8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956 ro single-8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956' {
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd1,gpt3'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt3 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt3 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt3  8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956
                fi
                linux /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.11-4-pve root=UUID=8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956 ro single
                initrd /boot/initrd.img-6.5.11-4-pve
        }
        menuentry 'Proxmox VE GNU/Linux, with Linux 6.2.16-20-pve (on /dev/sdb3)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-6.2.16-20-pve--8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956' {
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd1,gpt3'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt3 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt3 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt3  8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956
                fi
                linux /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.16-20-pve root=UUID=8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956 ro quiet
                initrd /boot/initrd.img-6.2.16-20-pve
        }
        menuentry 'Proxmox VE GNU/Linux, with Linux 6.2.16-20-pve (recovery mode) (on /dev/sdb3)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-6.2.16-20-pve-root=UUID=8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956 ro single-8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956' {
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd1,gpt3'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt3 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt3 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt3  8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956
                fi
                linux /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.16-20-pve root=UUID=8bbea8c8-2d32-426f-88fc-1720eea76956 ro single
                initrd /boot/initrd.img-6.2.16-20-pve
        }
}


This is more a system administration question than a development question, so I'm not sure this is the best place for it, but if you want to force the bootloader to be reinstalled, sudo NIXOS_INSTALL_BOOTLOADER=1 /run/current-system/bin/switch-to-configuration boot is the invocation I use on my laptop.

BTW, note that part of building a [mre] is finding the shortest/simplest configuration with the same problem. Does the problem go away when you take Docker out? If so, take Docker out for purposes of what you show when asking the question, and repeat for every other element until you've found the simplest possible configuration that still exhibits the problem.
